# How to adjust gamma correction on old monitors

Tags: display, screen, color

I am reusing two old monitors for which I found no custom way to set brightness, contrast, and gamma (see appendix below for full details). On a bright
background, the colors look dull and I want to change the gamma correction to
something close to a MacBook Pro retina display, which has sharp colors on the
same background.

On a Windows computer with the same monitor, I can change brightness, contrast, and gamma for the `NVIDIA GeForce GT 220` graphic card with the utility in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Control Panel Client\nvcplui.exe`. It shows three sliders for brightness, contrast, and gamma that have an immediate effect.

[image: NVIDIA tool to set brightness, contrast, and gamma]

On `macOS`, the `Display Calibrator Assistant` (from `System Preferences > Displays`) asks to change brightness and contrast with the monitor's buttons and to choose a white point. It says nothing about gamma, and does not change any of the settings.

With `ColorSync Utility`, I was able to view the ICC profile of the monitor and confirm it has gamma correction:

[image: Gamma correction for ICC profile]

I was also able to load a different profile (that of an LED Home Cinema Display that has sharp and crisp colors) but this made no difference on the monitor:

[image: Different display]

I have read [Set the color profile of my external monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302594/set-the-color-profile-of-my-external-monitor) and [Can I calibrate 2 screens to match, without buying expensive gear?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244928/can-i-calibrate-2-screens-to-match-without-buying-expensive-gear/244976) and still don't know how to change the gamma. I am on `macOS 10.14.6`.

Can I adjust brightness, contrast, and gamma of a monitor on macOS? If not, why is it impossible?

### details on monitors

The monitors are Samsung SyncMaster SA100 and S22A460. The monitor SA100 only has a power button. [This page](https://helper365.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-adjust-brightness-in-samsung-19.html) suggests an auto-adjustment by holding the on/off button for 10 seconds. This method works but the result is still dull (it's probably how it came).

I downloaded the latest MagicTune software for `macOS` from [this page](http://www.samsung.com/us/consumer/learningresources/monitor/magetune/pop_download.html), for `macOS 10.3.9-10.5.7` and the installer says:

```
This package is incompatible with this version of macOS and may fail to install.
```

The installation fails. I downloaded the latest version [for Windows
8](https://www.samsung.com/us/consumer/learningresources/monitor/magetune/pop_download.html),
MagicTune Premium 64 bit 4.0.36. No program of that name is in install in
`C:\Program Files`, but when I try to install again I get a warning that the
program is already installed.

I found [this page](http://freevbs.blogspot.com/p/computer.html) that addresses
the same problem. The third option mentions an open-source program, whose link
redirects to a blog where I found [the
tool](https://devoptions.blogspot.com/2013/03/monitor-brightness-adjustment-tool-for.html),
which is for Windows only. I installed .NET on a Windows computer and was able
to run the tool, but it only controls brightness, not contrast and
gamma:

[image: Adjustment tool on Windows]

Furthermore, the brightness setting does not port when I connect the
monitor to `macOS`, so the settings are probably saved on the Windows machine
and not on the monitor. The page does not provide the source code for me to have
a play (the 7-zip archive contains the executable).

On a SyncMaster S22A460, where I have buttons to control the display, I can
adjust the brightness and contrast but not the gamma.

Answer (score 1):

With your monitor connected, go to `System Preferences > Displays` and click on `Calibrate` with the Option key pressed down. This turns on the otherwise absent Expert Mode in the Display Calibrator Assistant.

[image]

This will present you with far greater control, including on about page 7 a Gamma adjust.

[image]

Nothing can replace a proper hardware colorimeter for screen calibration, but this will at least allow you to get closer.

Comment: This method worked for both monitors. If it fails for a monitor, try with other combinations, such as connecting the monitor before or after launching the Display Calibrator Assistant.

Comment: How would I use a proper hardware colorimeter in the case of the SyncMaster SA100 that has no hardware adjustments?

Comment: You don’t need controls on the screen. It can help but it’s not compulsory.

Comment: OK, I understand it now. It seems that a proper hardware colorimeter is outside a hobbyist's budget, is that right? I also found [this thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/why-not-use-a-camera-as-a-colorimeter) that does it with a DSLR and a smartphone camera, I might try that...